# How do I check whether a conditional value in dart is null without using a condition?

Tags: dart, conditional-statements, nullable

I have the following code:

```
 if(chatDocsListwithAuthUser != null) {
    for(ChatsRecord chatDoc in chatDocsListwithAuthUser) {
      if(chatDoc.users.contains(chatUser)) {
        return chatDoc;
      }
    }
  }
```

I get an error that says (for example) `chatDoc.users` can't be used in the condition because it might be null.

But I cannot put before it `if(chatDoc.users != null){...}` because that is also a condition!

What is the standard way when going through loops and conditionals within those loops to deal with nullability in dart?

For now, I use the following:
`if (chatDoc.users!.contains(chatUser)) {` but I don't know if this is right~!

Comment: Pay attention to the language of the error message.  It probably does *not* say "`chatDoc.users` cant be used in a condition".  It probably says something like "The method 'contains' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'."or "Method 'contains' cannot be called on ... because it is potentially null." In the future, please provide the exact error message you get instead of paraphrasing it.  Neither of those errors indicates that a condition cannot check `chatDoc.users != null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (chatDoc.users!.contains(chatUser))` will throw an error, if the `users` property is null. Instead, make the boolean value nullable and, if it is null, set it to false using `??` operator. So we will have the following condition:

```
if (chatDoc.users?.contains(chatUser) ?? false) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, The problem here is, you are saying the item has to be `ChatsRecord`. But in real, it can be null. So what you can do is make it `ChatRecord?`.
Example ->

```
if(chatDocsListwithAuthUser != null) {
 for(ChatsRecord? chatDoc in chatDocsListwithAuthUser) {
   if(chatDoc.users.contains(chatUser)) {
    return chatDoc;
    }
  }
}
```

Later inside the loop you can check, if the item is null or not. Like ->

```
if(chatDocsListwithAuthUser != null) {
 for(ChatsRecord? chatDoc in chatDocsListwithAuthUser) {
   if(chatDoc != null && chatDoc.users.contains(chatUser)) {
       return chatDoc;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, so check first for the full list.  But am I allowed to put in an if statement chatDoc != null)?

Comment: @satchel Yes brother. You can definitely do that. I've done it too here. In my `if statement` first I'm checking if the `chatDoc` is null or not. Then also checking if the user list contains it. If you want, you can separate the `if function` in 2 different `if function`s.

Comment: okay I think I see.  I guess I felt I could never check for a value using 'if' statements.  Thanks @Hippo Fish